# Error found when to unwrap the optional dictionaries element in swift

Tags: xcode7

Run the followings swift codes in the 'Playground' but line2 get an error as shown below, why cannot access the optional value for the `dictTest[1]!` ?

```
var dictTest: [Int:String]? = [1:"A"]
dictTest[1]!
```

error:

> value of optional type '[Int : String]?' not unwrapped; did you mean
>   to use '!' or '?'? dictTest[1]!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the swift's code as shown below :

var dictTest: [Int:String]? = [1:"A"]

var dictTest2: [Int:String] = dictTest!

dictTest2[1]

I think the trick is that we have to unwrap the optional value before use it. Anyone who have the best answer, please advise!